Are these generated from my code the so called feature maps?
I assume that the way people build which activations detect specific pieces from an image is by executing the network and extracting the results at each layer; when the output is from a convolutional layer, it is called feature map (to my understanding.)
My question is whether it's correct to actually say this is a feature map, and this is the result of running the network each time up to a specific depth (excepting the layers that I discard.)
The image I generate (which this question is about.) is at the bottom.
Am I correct assuming that layer.output here is a KerasTensor that remembers all transformations (and weights) up to that point?
So it's not reaaaally a symbolic tensor here.
The code, in case you want to run it, based off keras docs, that does that as an example, in a notebook, the code is:
!pip install tensorflow[and-cuda]==2.16.1 keras==3.3.3

import os
os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "tensorflow"

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras import ops
from keras import layers
import imageio as iio
from PIL import Image

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# retrieve vgg19
vgg19 = keras.applications.VGG19()

# get the tensors, and presumably the history as well
features_list = [layer.output for layer in vgg19.layers]

# I'm unsure how keras interprets the list, but it seems that
# it will contain all operations
feat_extraction_model = keras.Model(inputs=vgg19.input, outputs=features_list)

# test on an image from internet (a dog.)
img=iio.imread("https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/54822a56e4b0b30bd821480c/29708160-9b39-42d0-a5ed-4f8b9c85a267/labrador+retriever+dans+pet+care.jpeg?format=1500w")
img = Image.fromarray(img).resize((224, 224))
plt.imshow(img)

# print(img.shape)
img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image=img, dtype="float32")
img = tf.expand_dims(img,axis=0)
img = img.numpy().astype("float32")

extracted_features = feat_extraction_model(img)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
columns = 4
rows = 7

for i, v in enumerate(extracted_features):
    f = tf.squeeze(extracted_features[i])
    if len(f.shape) != 3:
        continue
    if f.shape[-1] > 3:
        print(f.shape)
        f = f[:,:,0:3] # use 3 channels so we can plot
    pil_img = keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(f)
    fig.add_subplot(rows, columns, i+1)
    plt.imshow(pil_img)
    # time.sleep(10)
plt.show()


I get this:

